# Put/Get UploadField submitted image from custom Form -> Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: image, forms, file, silverstripe

I have a small problem programming with the use of **UploadField** . I have created pages to make a light CMS on the FrontEnd. But I don't know how retrieve this image to the page «Update».

There is the code from the page «Create» :

```
$uploadField = new UploadField( 'ImageEvenement', 'Image' );
```

There is the code I tried to get working for the page «Update»

```
$evenID = Session::get('evenementID');
$evenement = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);
..
$SavedImage = File::get()->byID($evenement->ImageEvenementID)
$uploadField = new UploadField( 'ImageEvenement', 'Image', $SavedImage );
```

How can I retrieve the submitted image to **$SavedImage** ? My idea to get the ID from File don't work.

Another method :

```
$SavedImage = $evenement->ImageEvenement();
```

If I dump data from $SavedImage I'm viewing :

```
Image Object
(
    [destroyed] => 
    [model:protected] => DataModel Object
        (
            [customDataLists:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [record:protected] => Array
        (
            [ClassName] => Image
            [Created] => 2015-07-15 14:41:24
            [LastEdited] => 2015-07-16 15:03:25
            [Name] => images.jpg
            [Title] => images
            [Filename] => assets/Membres/9/calendrier/images.jpg
            [ShowInSearch] => 1
            [ParentID] => 15
            [OwnerID] => 9
            [ID] => 22
            [RecordClassName] => Image
        )

    [changed:DataObject:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [ClassName] => Image
            [Created] => 2015-07-15 14:41:24
            [LastEdited] => 2015-07-16 15:03:25
            [Name] => images.jpg
            [Title] => images
            [Filename] => assets/Membres/9/calendrier/images.jpg
            [ShowInSearch] => 1
            [ParentID] => 15
            [OwnerID] => 9
            [ID] => 22
            [RecordClassName] => Image
        )

    [brokenOnDelete:protected] => 
    [brokenOnWrite:protected] => 
    [components:protected] => 
    [unsavedRelations:protected] => 
    [sourceQueryParams:protected] => 
    [failover:protected] => 
    [customisedObject:protected] => 
    [objCache:ViewableData:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [class] => Image
    [extension_instances:protected] => Array
        (
            [BetterButtonDataObject] => BetterButtonDataObject Object
                (
                    [owner:protected] => 
                    [ownerBaseClass:protected] => DataObject
                    [ownerRefs:Extension:private] => 0
                    [class] => BetterButtonDataObject
                )

            [SiteTreeFileExtension] => SiteTreeFileExtension Object
                (
                    [owner:protected] => 
                    [ownerBaseClass:protected] => File
                    [ownerRefs:Extension:private] => 0
                    [class] => SiteTreeFileExtension
                )

            [Hierarchy] => Hierarchy Object
                (
                    [markedNodes:protected] => 
                    [markingFilter:protected] => 
                    [_cache_numChildren:protected] => 
                    [owner:protected] => 
                    [ownerBaseClass:protected] => File
                    [ownerRefs:Extension:private] => 0
                    [class] => Hierarchy
                )

        )

    [beforeExtendCallbacks:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [afterExtendCallbacks:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Any idea?

```
class PageCalendrierEvenement extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        "Titre" => "Varchar(50)",
        "DateDepart" => "Date",
        "DateFin" => "Date",
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Creator' => 'Member',
        'ImageEvenement' => 'Image',
    );

..
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the relevant $db and $has_one sections of your page and dataobjects? How is Image related to the current page?

Comment: Ok I have pasted to code above. Thank you!

Comment: class PageCalendrierEvenement extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        "Titre" => "Varchar(50)",
        "DateDepart" => "Date",
        "DateFin" => "Date",
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Creator' => 'Member',
        'ImageEvenement' => 'Image',
    );

..
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code works fine but are not clean and not using SilverStripe function classes. The reason for non working saving images to dataobject, is because that I have not use :

```
$form->saveInto($evenement)
```

I would like to thank you [Wmk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137738/wmk) for give me the get method to fill form with values on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031681/silverstripe-write-page-to-live-stage-or-draft-how-it-works) :

```
$form->loadDataForm($evenement)
```

Finaly, all works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

has one relations need the "ID" suffix in the name of the relation (as it's saved to db...), e.g.

```
$uploadField = new UploadField( 'ImageEvenementID', 'Image', $SavedImage );
```

then it should save automatically.

OR, what i do for a single relation:

```
$imageField = UploadField::create('ImageEvenement', 'Image');
$imageField->setAllowedFileCategories('image');
$imageField->setAllowedMaxFileNumber(1);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Adding ID to the ImageEvenement dont work, when I'm submitting the form, I have a 'server error' message... but the second part of your message help me resolve another problem ;)

Comment: Just a little precision on my problem. Adding the image from uploadfield works and store it into database works too. My problem is to show/retrieve that image to uploadfield on a custom update 'evenement' page. All fields appear on fields but not the uploadfield... I hope my english is not so bad ;) thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly after long time brain searching, I have found the trick! The command to use with UploadField is **setValue($value)** with **fileIDs** include with it. My final code is :

```
$evenement = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);

...

$uploadField = new UploadField( 'ImageEvenement', 'Image' );

$data['ImageID'] = $evenement->ImageEvenement()->ID; 

$fileIDs[]=$data['ImageID'];
$uploadField->setValue(array('Files' => $fileIDs));
```

Thats it!