# Silverstripe write Page to Live, stage or Draft? How it works

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have some difficulty to update a page by selecting is version... To Create, I do this :

```
$PageCalendrierEvenement = new PageCalendrierEvenement();

$PageCalendrierEvenement->Title = $this->request->postVar('Titre');
$PageCalendrierEvenement->MenuTitle = $this->request->postVar('Titre');
$PageCalendrierEvenement->URLSegment = Utils::remplacerEspaces(Utils::remplacerAccents($PageCalendrierEvenement->Titre));
$PageCalendrierEvenement->publish('Stage');
$PageCalendrierEvenement->doRestoreToStage();
```

That work's very well. But how can we update it values by ID? Is it possible witout using DB:Query?

```
$evens = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);
$evens->Title = $this->request->postVar(Titre);
$evens->Publish('Stage');
```

Comment: What is `PageCalendrierEvenement()`? A subclass of SiteTree or Page or a plain DataObject? Generelly it's better (IMHO), to code in plain english, so others understand better what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For subclasses of SiteTree you can just do:

```
$evens = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);
$evens->Title = $this->request->postVar(Titre);

//do whatever you want...

$evens->doPublish(); //writes to Stage and Live and does other stuff for SiteTree
```

For simple DataObjects you need to call:

```
//changed a bit...
$evens->write();
$evens->publish("Stage", "Live");
```

[See source...](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-SiteTree.html#2316-2359)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. doPublish function works great. But I have another problem. How can I retreive values from a siteTree page and populate it into a custom form? is the setValue($values) is the only way? If yes, which is the best method to get the page variable. Actually I'm using this : `$evens = Versioned::get_by_stage('PageCalendrierEvenement', 'Stage')->byID($evenID);` Im getting values from an ID of a draft page. After I get variables and values like that : `$field=new TextField('Titre','Titre'); $field->setValue($evens->Titre)` or `new TextField('Titre','Titre', $evens->Titre ); `

Comment: If my answer works fine you might "accept" the answer (and maybe upvote it). For the other question you might start a new topic. But as you already asked: $form->loadDataFrom($myObject) fills the already generated form with data from another DataObject, see API docs: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Form.html#_loadDataFrom

Comment: Thanks for answer and advise!

Comment: @StéphaneGuevremont can you accept the answer if it solved your problem?